# for ループの計算結果で表示される値が想定と違う

Tags: java

このプログラムの場合表示される数値って5050ではないのですか？

```
public class Sum { 
    static int sum = 0;  
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        for (int i = 1, sum = 0; i <= 100; i++) {   
            sum = sum + i;    
        }  
        System.out.println("sum="+ sum); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

for ループの `, sum = 0` が余計ですね。

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {   
    sum = sum + i;    
}
```

なら、ご想像通りです。

元の状態だと、for ループのブロック内のローカル変数として sum が定義され、`static int sum` の sum とは別扱いです。そのためループを抜けると、ローカル変数 sum は関係がなくなり、println で初期値の 0 のままの static int sum の値がプリントされます。